# A count from multiple base in single query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL databases i want to count number of rows in two tables on each database and combine results.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM base_1.users;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       15 |
+----------+
SELECT count(*) FROM base_2.users;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       75 |
+----------+
```

This query return result of first count.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM base_1.users, base_2.users;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       15 |
+----------+
```

Can i make it in single query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UNION ALL` between the two queries and then use `SUM()` to get the total:

```
select sum(total) as TotalCount
from
(
  SELECT count(*) Total
  FROM base_1.users
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) 
  FROM base_2.users
) src
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SELECT SUM(c)
FROM 
(
   SELECT count(*) as c FROM base_1.users;
) x
UNION
(
   SELECT count(*) as c FROM base_2.users;
) y
```